# How can I connect to the remote machine through a bastion-host machine via ssh?

Tags: visual-c++, ssh, remote-server

I have installed [*Visual C++ 2015 for Linux*.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCppDevLabs.VisualCforLinuxDevelopment) What this does is, it takes a server name, a port number, a username, and a password, then connects to the remote machine, compiles a C++ program inside that machine, and then returns the result to my local PC.

[image]

Now, the problem I am facing is, I have to connect to the remote PC through a bastion-host machine. I don't know how to do that.

How can I connect to a remote machine through a bastion-host machine via ssh?

Comment: if visual studio itself can't do a 2 step ssh tunnel, you can always open an SSH tunnel externally to visual studio and then tell visual studio to conect to that tunnel on localhost

Comment: What do you mean by gateway? Is it a bastion host running linux? Is it a NATting router?

Comment: @tink, a bastion host running linux. The remote PC is also running Linux. However, I am running Windows 10.

Comment: As Erik said: [Use a local ssh tunnel](https://google.com/search?q=windows+10+ssh+tunnel) ... a link rather than an answer because a) I don't use/have windows and b) I don't know whether you prefer command line or putty ;)